Angular AuthGuard not working in hostinger websi
I hosted our in Hostinger. I am using CanActivate AuthGuard but when I try to just to refresh the page, it says this.
Oops, looks like the page is lost.
This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional.
auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenService } from '../services/token.service';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

    setToken(token: string): void {
        this.tokenService.setToken(token);
    }
    
    isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return !!this.tokenService.getToken();
    }

}

auth.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../authguard/auth.service';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard  {
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        const isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }

}

app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
// import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SharedFileComponent } from './shared-file/shared-file.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DriveComponent } from './drive/drive.component';
import { DocumentsComponent } from './drive/user/documents/documents.component';
import { MediaComponent } from './drive/user/media/media.component';
import { OthersComponent } from './drive/user/others/others.component';
import { RecentComponent } from './recent/recent.component';
import { StarredComponent } from './starred/starred.component';
import { TrashComponent } from './trash/trash.component';
import { FolderComponent } from './folder/folder.component';
import { TagsComponent } from './tags/tags.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './authguard/auth.guard';
import { LoginGuard } from './authguard/login.guard';

// const routes: Routes = \[
//   // {path:'', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
//   // {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
//   { path: 'login', loadChildren: () =\> import('./login/login.module').then(m =\> m.LoginModule) },
//   {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
//   {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
//   {path:'sharedFile', component: SharedFileComponent},
// \];

const routes: Routes = \[
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: \[LoginGuard\] },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/drive', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'folder', component: FolderComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\]},
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\] },
{ path: 'sharedFile', component: SharedFileComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\] },
{ path: 'drive/folder/:id', component: FolderComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\]},
{
path: 'drive',
component: DriveComponent,
children: \[
{
path: 'documents',
component: DocumentsComponent
},
{
path: 'media',
component: MediaComponent
},
{
path: 'others',
component: OthersComponent

      }
    ], canActivate: [AuthGuard]

},
{ path: 'recent', component: RecentComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\]},
{ path: 'starred', component: StarredComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\] },
{ path: 'trash', component: TrashComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\]},
{ path: 'tags', title: 'Tags - GCloud', component: TagsComponent, canActivate: \[AuthGuard\]},
{ path: '\*\*', redirectTo: '/login' }
\];

@NgModule({
imports: \[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)\],
exports: \[RouterModule\]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

token.service.ts I'm not sure if I need to include this
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  setToken(token: string): void {
    this.cookieService.set('token', token);
    console.log("Token: " + token); // Set the token in a cookie
  }

  flushToken() {
    console.log("delete token");
    this.cookieService.delete('token', '/');
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.cookieService.get('token');
  } 

  decodeToken() {
    const usertoken = this.getToken();
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(usertoken);
    return decodedToken;
  }

  usernameToken(decodedToken: any): string {
    if (decodedToken && decodedToken.data && decodedToken.data.name) {
      return decodedToken.data.name;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  userIDToken(decodedToken: any): number {
    if (decodedToken && decodedToken.data && decodedToken.data.user) {    
      return decodedToken.data.user;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  userEmailToken(decodedToken: any): string {
    if (decodedToken && decodedToken.data && decodedToken.data.email) {
      return decodedToken.data.email;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  } 
  
}```

I need to go the link of the website itself without the /login. For instance, I need to go to website.com for it not to cause the error. If I refresh the page in website.com/login, it will say the error.

